# autocomplete in codeigniter not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

Hy, i am making an autocomplete search field in codeigniter,I tried to do autocomplete in codeignter using the below code .But it is not working for me.Not displaying anything in the autocomplete text field.Can anyone find the problem

success function of data displaying as undefined

Here is my view:

```
View
 <script >
     $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#trackerid").change(function(){
        var var_locoid= $("#trackerid option:selected").val();
        alert(var_locoid);
        $( "#deliverylocation" ).autocomplete({

            source: function(request, response) {
                var auto_data= $("#deliverylocation").val();
                      alert(auto_data);

                //alert(var_locoid);
               $.ajax({
                 url:"http://localhost/testcontroller/test/lookup",
                 type:"POST",
                 datatype:'json',
                 data:{'var_locoid' :var_locoid,'auto_data':auto_data},
                 success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
        });
    });});
     </script>

                                <input type="text" name="deliverylocation" id="deliverylocation" placeholder="Enter your area " >
```

Controller

```
    function lookup()
{
   $citys = $this->input->post('var_locoid'); 
      $auto_text = $this->input->post('auto_data');  

                    //var_dump($citys);
         //$data['response'] = 'false'; 
  $place = $this->Demo_model->load_places($citys,array('keyword' => $auto_text));   
    $json_array = array();
    foreach ($place as $row){
    array_push($json_array, $row->locationtext);
    }
           //echo json_encode($place);
   echo json_encode($json_array);
}



Model

function load_places($citys,$auto_text)
    {
        //$this->db->select('locationtext');
        $this->db->select('locationtext');
        $this->db->like('locationtext', $auto_text);
        $this->db->from('tbl_location');
        $array = array('cityautocode' => $citys);
        $this->db->where($array);
        //$this->db->->where('cityautcode', $place);
         $query= $this->db->get();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();

          return $query->result();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using an autocomplete pattern from https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Here is my controller:

```
$arrayData = $this->CRUD_model->getSelect("id as data, name as value, purchase_price","articles")->result_array();
    echo json_encode($arrayData);
```

And my views:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse");
    var dataArticles = $.parseJSON(getArticles());
    $("input[name='articles_name']").devbridgeAutocomplete({
        lookup: dataArticles,
        onSelect: function(suggestion) {
            $("input[name='articles_id']").val(suggestion.data);
        },
        showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
        noSuggestionNotice: 'Barang tidak ditemukan',
        noCache: true,
        minChars: 2,
    })
})

function getArticles(){
    result = null;
    $.ajax({url: '<?= base_url();?>panel/purchasing/request/getArticles',type: 'get',dataType: 'html',async: false,success: function(data) {result = data;} });
    return result;
}
```

For this example I use lookup, so all autocomplete values loaded when I open the page, note that id must be named "data" and label must be named "value".